# Exposing public methods and properties on jQuery plugins (Using object dot-notation)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for examples of how to best expose public methods and properties on jQuery plugins.

I've already studied the [jQuery plugin authoring tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), but I would rather have some options for exposing methods/properties in standard object-oriented dot-notation `$(selector).myplugin.myfunction()`, rather than having to pass the method name as a string argument, which just annoys me.

Does anyone have alternative techniques?

Thanks-

Answer (score 1):

Well outside of JQuery, objects in javascript are just key value pairs.  Your JQuery plugin can just return a hash where keys are bound to functions and achieve what you are asking for:

Example:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function() {

  return {one: function(){alert('one');}}

};
$('html').myPlugin().one()
```

The above is completely contrived but its just to show you an example.

Comment: Note that this breaks the jQuery convention of always returning jQuery. You'll be breaking the jQuery chain so to speak. Normally you can do: `$(document).yourPlugin().myPlugin();` but if you do this, obviously the `.myPlugin()` won't work because you're not returning the jQuery reference where `myPlugin` is defined.